# React useEffect() hook highly affects SEO

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have a static website made with react that requests data from the backend in the `useEffect()` hook:

```
export default const App = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState("");
    
    useEffect(() => {
        server.get().then(data => {
          setData(data)
         })
     })
    
    return(
      <title>{data}</title>
      <h1>{data}</h1>
    )
}
```

However, when Bing crawls the webpage, the following problem occurs:

Bing Screenshot:

```
<title></title>
<h1></h1>
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

React isn't used for static sites. If you'd like to have better SEO and server-side rendering you can use [nextjs](https://nextjs.org/).

The way your app is setup currently will only return some HTML with and empty body to a `GET` request to `/` (which is what I suppose crawlers like the one you mentioned use) and starts rendering components after the JavaScript is loaded.

But if you decide on a server-side rendering approach, whenever a request is made to your app the server will first render the app on it's side and the return an HTML string with the rendered components.

Comment: I am using Netlify SSR.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if your server.get() is returning some data? I can't see any url here, so maybe it's actually returning nothing.

Even so, maybe you forgot to pass the second argument of useEffect, which is an array of arguments, which this hooks uses to trigger itself. For example, if you want to trigger only once, when component is mounted, you need to pass `[]` as second argument of useEffect.

Comment: The Server returns data after the Website has loaded, but the bots scanning the website do not wait until then